# How do we express something moving exactly the same way we move?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Say, I am standing in front of a mirror and I move, my reflection will move accordingly.

Or

I see my shadow on the wall and when I move, it moves accordingly.

Is it correct to say "**My reflection/shadow moves in tandem with me**" in casual/everyday conversation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that sounds too wordy for everyday speech. Besides, the usage is not quite right; "move in tandem" means to *work together* but not necessarily to do the *exact same motions* as someone else.

I would use the verb [**mirror**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mirror#Verb):

> My reflection mirrors my actions.

Comment: Can "to mirror" be used with "shadow"?

Comment: Yeah, I would say it can. "To mirror" and "to shadow" have (depending on context) almost identical meanings, so you can interchange them to avoid sounding redundant.